# How can I read this url in Rebol?

Tags: rebol

when trying to read this kind of url

URL: http://v4.lscache2.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?ip=0.0.0.0&sparams=id,expire,ip,ipbits,itag,algorithm,burst,factor,oc:U0dWSlhTVF9FSkNNNl9QTVhJ&algorithm=throttle-factor&itag=34&ipbits=0&burst=40&sver=3&expire=1275886800&key=yt1&signature=89195E808CB3FBBC7BDE7298A1DC0613D7987F00.D3064112E8F479C523F8DF4FBFDF392CE48167C2&factor=1.25&id=34e01ad39b34b5c9&

I get this error

> > read/binary url
> >     connecting to: v4.lscache2.c.youtube.com
> >     ** User Error: Error.  Target url: http://v4.lscache2.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?ip=0.0.0.0&sparams=id,expire,ip,ipbits,
> >     itag,algorithm...
> >     ** Near: read/binary url

Answer (score 1):

In Rebol 3 you get:

```
** Access error: protocol error: "Server error: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"
```

The message you're getting is Rebol 2's not-so-eloquent way of saying that.  (You can also enter it in Firebug and see that using this raw URL does not work.)

I'd imagine that YouTube will only let you get the stream if the requesting HTTP header matches a certain pattern.  Among potential things it might look for is a cookie specifically crafted for your session and designed to expire after a certain time.

As far as I understand it YouTube is not too keen on third party downloads of video data.  They used to have a `get_video` API but appear to have disabled it.  So you'll either have to fake up a cookie and make them think you're one of their players, or find a service which is friendlier to this sort of application.

Comment: This url is not a visible url: it is the real url for the video I found with http://www.web-video-downloader.com/. 

I can get the video with no problem by just pasting it into browser, I don't have to send any special header. So there should logically be a solution in rebol also don't you agree ?

Comment: Well your experience is different from mine.  When I paste it in Chrome I get a blank page.  When I go into a debugging environment (e.g. Firebug) I get a 403 error.  Unsure what browser you use, but try emptying the cache and then pasting the URL... I'd be surprised if your results were different than mine...

Comment: You can see the same error in R2 by putting trace/net on, and then opening the url instead of reading it.